# Mobile chatting doesn't clear pings

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web, global-inbox

I've been chatting from mobile today (with my Galaxy SIII), seems like when people ping me, it doesn't matter whether I send messages, or even specifically ping them back, the notification doesn't get cleared, and it eventually reaches my inbox with a flurry of 14 inbox notifications.

[image: Screenshot]

I've read other threads close to the subject, but it doesn't seem like anything addressed this specifically, so I'm opening this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report here.

Comment: +1 happening same to me in android browser ....

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't seem to duplicate this on my iPhone 5, either in the mobile site or the full site on mobile.

Comment: *[blames Marc](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=441980#441980)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's now possible to acknowledge mentions in mobile chat (acknowledge means "tell the server I saw this message"; only messages that haven't been acknowledged in ~15 minutes will be pushed to the inbox).

Unlike in the desktop version, this acknowledgement has to happen manually in the mobile version. It is much easier to miss a mention in the mobile chat, because there's no "(3)" counter of unread mentions, and usually there are fewer messages being displayed. So in the mobile version, we don't make the assumption "if they speak, they have seen the mentions."

But from now on, undismissed mentions are highlighted in mobile chat:

[image: screenshot of mobile chat with a highlighted mention]

Just click (tap) anywhere on the message to remove the marker and ackowledge the message.

Comment: Huh? What platform is this? Or is the (mention) thingy new?

Comment: Yes, it's new, as the answer says.

Comment: I would never say such a thing to you @balpha - who do you think I am?  :)

Comment: @Geoff You have only yourself to blame for your 1-digit user id that makes you a perfect target for ad-hoc impersonation.